# What is an archaic, rare noun or word for an archetypal, vengeant, past tensive male character who is of the past that many aspire to be like?

Tags: past-tense, archaicisms, old-english, obscure-terms, antimeria

What I mean is "someone of old" that people could be drawn to. One who is stuck in the past and in his ways and dislikes the future.

Something like:
• an originator
• an innovator
• a predecessor
• an uncaused, time-traveler.

Edit: This character also could have nefarious, mysterious, dismissive or even obsolete characteristics in his personality traits, yet rapidly breaks free from them in a rather vengeant manner.

Comment: Um . . . God???  Adam???  What precisely are you asking for here?

Comment: Of human descent, a diamond in the rough and deals with matters in a rather vengeant manner.

Comment: I don't particularly understand why you would be seeking an archaic word?  Do you mean a archetypal character?

Comment: Archetypal character that practices the qualities above sounds about right, and an uncommon word for that type of character, more specifically ending in er, or, ist.

Comment: Is it OK if the word can be applied to women, or must it exclude them?

Comment: It's okay if the word is a verb ending in er, or, ing, though an old, ancient, uncommon, or rare masculine word if possible.

Comment: Whst is a past tensive male?

Comment: Trying to portray a male character absolutely and indefinitely living in the past, preterite, completes actions in a time before now and watches the newcomers executing his hallmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Archetype**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archetype):

> a statement, pattern of behavior, a prototype, a "first" form or a main model which other statements, patterns of behavior, and objects copy, emulate or "merge" into. (Frequently used informal synonyms for this usage include "standard example", "basic example", and the longer form "archetypal example". Mathematical archetypes often appear as "canonical examples".)

Someone who is an archetypal character is someone who represents the primal nature of man.

Comment: Archetypal and Canonical combined, merged into man, any close ancient synonyms? definitely "primal" or "first" which peers would like to emulate. Said character in his prime form would contain glorious, majestic, or mystique traits.

Comment: @Uncaused There are numerous archetypal characters that meet those descriptions.  The wise old man.  The noble savage.  etc.

Comment: In this case his ability of being an Archetypal character is his only, savant strength. His kryptonite is a scandalous woman. yet he remains in his defensive mechanisms.

Comment: @Uncaused Samson

Comment: In essence a word, verb or past participle of an archetypal character similar to Samson, in relation to Samson, Samson being the predecessor of this "revolutionary new spin" if you will, of Samson in this day and era. modernized.

Comment: @Uncaused Modern-day Samson works for me.

Comment: Found this Noun

Archetier (plural archetiers)

(lutherie) One who builds, repairs, and restores the bows of instruments in the violin family. Replace the bows and instruments with the character's life situations.